# Wordpress live build not mirroring dev build

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I built a Wordpress site locally using MAMP, where I set up a page with a custom page template which displays a custom post type in a certain format. When I moved everything across to the live server, the custom page template doesn't work as I expected, and just shows what I assume is a default posts archive page (see example: http://www.hiblio.tv/rewind). What's weird is that if I set up a new page with a different permalink, it works fine (example: http://www.hiblio.tv/archive).

I've tried deleting both pages, removing them from the trash and starting again, but whatever I do, I can't get the page to display properly with the 'Rewind' url, which is where I need it to go. Any ideas?

Comment: Are both wordpress versions the same? Are you following WP theming guide on file names? [WP Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Comment: Both wordpress versions are the same. I've saved the template in the root folder of my theme as page-templates/rewind.php, do i need to call it archive-rewind.php?

Comment: Yessss ;) Always follow the template hierarchy and you'll be good to go